# QGIS Data Source Manager - Geopackage - Connection path listing not updated

Tags: qgis-3, geopackage

I migrated all my databases from one server to another and have re-pathed the layers in each project file.
I also updated the QGIS3.ini file, where the [providers] tag was listing the connection paths.

So now when i load QGIS, and open the Data Source Manager, the drop down listing still refer's to the old path (P drive in this instance), however when selecting one of these, the path is the new path. See screen grab below.

So my question is - **how can I change the path that is showing in the dropdown?** It doesn't appear to be in the QGIS3.ini file, but maybe ive missed something.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, it appears as though I had a session still hanging in the background. Once I completely shutdown and restarted all sessions, the connection path on the dropdown updated to the new path.